# AWS Composite Alarm - Auto scaling action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I have created two Alarms to scale up my instance count,

1. Cpu Utilization > 20
2. Target Response Time > 10

Then I have created a Composite alarm to go to ALARM state if Alarm 1 or 2  Triggered. Now I want to remove the above-mentioned Alarms from  Scaling policies and use the composite alarm for Auto Scaling.
Is it possible? If so, how can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Milan has already mentioned, composite alarms cannot be used in autoscaling policies. However, you can make a conditional alarm (if cpu>20 || target response >10) for 'n' minutes, go in alarm state. This way you can use this alarm in your autoscaling policy.

Answer (score 5):

when we want to create custom alerts with mutliple metrics we can use math expressions.
for ex: i want to create an alert with the combination of mem and cpu utilization so check the both mem and cpu metrics of service and click on the **Add math -> conditional -> AND** . then it will give you a new metric like e1 expression. and also we can edit that expression by using if conditions.

math expression example e1: **IF( m1 < 30 && c1 < 30 , 1,0)**
which means when memory avg and cpu avg are less than 30 then only you graph on 1 else go to 0. now you can setup alarm between 0 and 1 and add an action to this alaram.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Composite alarms cannot be used in Autoscaling Policies.